# Angular2 Component inside ngFor throws Error (viewFactory is not a function)

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-template

I have a a ComponentB in a Angular 2 app (beta 1). It works perfectly fine until I place it inside a ngFor loop in ComponentA. I receive the rather cryptic error of:

> EXCEPTION: TypeError: viewFactory_ComponentB0 is not a function in [numbers in ComponentA@1:23]BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ angular2.dev.js:22690BrowserDomAdapter.logGroup @ angular2.dev.js:22701ExceptionHandler.call @ angular2.dev.js:1163(anonymous function) @ angular2.dev.js:12416NgZone._notifyOnError @ angular2.dev.js:13324collection_1.StringMapWrapper.merge.onError @ angular2.dev.js:13228run @ angular2-polyfills.js:141(anonymous function) @ angular2.dev.js:13247NgZone.run @ angular2.dev.js:13209(anonymous function) @ angular2.dev.js:12499schedulerFn @ angular2.dev.js:12742tryCatcher @ Rx.js:31Subscriber.next @ Rx.js:9500Subject._next @ Rx.js:9999Subject.next @ Rx.js:9963EventEmitter.emit @ angular2.dev.js:12723(anonymous function) @ angular2.dev.js:13140run @ angular2-polyfills.js:138NgZone._notifyOnTurnDone @ angular2.dev.js:13139(anonymous function) @ angular2.dev.js:13254zoneBoundFn @ angular2-polyfills.js:111lib$es6$promise$asap$$flush @ angular2-polyfills.js:1305
>   angular2.dev.js:22690 ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: viewFactory_ComponentB0 is not a functionBrowserDomAdapter.logError @ angular2.dev.js:22690ExceptionHandler.call @ angular2.dev.js:1172(anonymous function) @ angular2.dev.js:12416NgZone._notifyOnError @ angular2.dev.js:13324collection_1.StringMapWrapper.merge.onError @ angular2.dev.js:13228run @ angular2-polyfills.js:141(anonymous function) @ angular2.dev.js:13247NgZone.run @ angular2.dev.js:13209(anonymous function) @ angular2.dev.js:12499schedulerFn @ angular2.dev.js:12742tryCatcher @ Rx.js:31Subscriber.next @ Rx.js:9500Subject._next @ Rx.js:9999Subject.next @ Rx.js:9963EventEmitter.emit @ angular2.dev.js:12723(anonymous function) @ angular2.dev.js:13140run @ angular2-polyfills.js:138NgZone._notifyOnTurnDone @ angular2.dev.js:13139(anonymous function) @ angular2.dev.js:13254zoneBoundFn @ angular2-polyfills.js:111lib$es6$promise$asap$$flush @ angular2-polyfills.js:1305
>   angular2.dev.js:22690 ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ angular2.dev.js:22690ExceptionHandler.call @ angular2.dev.js:1175(anonymous function) @ angular2.dev.js:12416NgZone._notifyOnError @ angular2.dev.js:13324collection_1.StringMapWrapper.merge.onError @ angular2.dev.js:13228run @ angular2-polyfills.js:141(anonymous function) @ angular2.dev.js:13247NgZone.run @ angular2.dev.js:13209(anonymous function) @ angular2.dev.js:12499schedulerFn @ angular2.dev.js:12742tryCatcher @ Rx.js:31Subscriber.next @ Rx.js:9500Subject._next @ Rx.js:9999Subject.next @ Rx.js:9963EventEmitter.emit @ angular2.dev.js:12723(anonymous function) @ angular2.dev.js:13140run @ angular2-polyfills.js:138NgZone._notifyOnTurnDone @ angular2.dev.js:13139(anonymous function) @ angular2.dev.js:13254zoneBoundFn @ angular2-polyfills.js:111lib$es6$promise$asap$$flush @ angular2-polyfills.js:1305
>   angular2.dev.js:22690 TypeError: viewFactory_ComponentB0 is not a function
>       at AppElement.viewFactory_ComponentA1 [as embeddedViewFactory] (viewFactory_ComponentA:388)
>       at AppViewManager_.createEmbeddedViewInContainer (angular2.dev.js:9185)
>       at ViewContainerRef_.createEmbeddedView (angular2.dev.js:5890)
>       at NgFor._bulkInsert (angular2.dev.js:14608)
>       at NgFor._applyChanges (angular2.dev.js:14567)
>       at NgFor.ngDoCheck (angular2.dev.js:14552)
>       at AbstractChangeDetector.ChangeDetector_ComponentA_0.detectChangesInRecordsInternal (viewFactory_ComponentA:45)
>       at AbstractChangeDetector.detectChangesInRecords (angular2.dev.js:7825)
>       at AbstractChangeDetector.runDetectChanges (angular2.dev.js:7808)
>       at AbstractChangeDetector._detectChangesInViewChildren (angular2.dev.js:7892)

ComponentA:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'component-a'
  , directives: [
    FORM_DIRECTIVES
    , ComponentB
  ]
  , template: `
    <!-- works --><component-b [(ngFormControl)]="_formControl"></component-b>
    <!-- fails --><component-b *ngFor="#number of numbers" [(ngFormControl)]="_formControls[number]"></component-b>
  `
})

export class ComponentA {}
```

Any hints/help highly appreciated.

Comment: This is a bug introduced in beta.1 (see [#6404](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6404)). There's already a fix (see [#6474](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/6474)) for it, so you'll have to wait for the next release and downgrade to beta.0 if you want to avoid these bugs.

Comment: Will you provide plnkr?

Comment: I downgraded to beta.0 as @EricMartinez pointed out and it works again now.

Comment: @EricMartinez could you post your answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @TylerDurden sure thing, done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As suggested by @TylerDurden

This error message is produced by a bug introduced in cycle detection (see [#6404](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6404)).

There's already a fix in master (see [#6474](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/6474)) not yet released. This will for sure be in beta.2.

The recommendation is to downgrade to beta.0 until the storm is over.

## Update

This issue has been fixed in beta.2 (issues with minification are still there). See [changelog](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) for more details.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up. I've been stuck trying to figure out a workaround for hours.

Answer (score 1):

Is this problem really solved? I was working on the "beta 0" and the following code worked for me, but when updating files beta 2 still gives me the same problem as in this post. This is my code:

```
// rowIterator.component.ts
import {Component,forwardRef} from 'angular2/core';
import {ColumIteratorComponent} from './columIterator.component';
import {ModuleIteratorComponent} from './moduleIterator.component';

@Component({
  selector: '[rowIterator]',
  template: `
    <div *ngFor="#element of rowData">
      <div columIterator *ngIf="element.column" [ngClass]="element.class" [columData]="element.column"></div>

      <div moduleIterator *ngIf="element.module" [ngClass]="element.class" [moduleData]="element.module"></div>
    </div>
    `,
  inputs: ['rowData'],
  directives: [forwardRef(function() { return ColumIteratorComponent; }),ModuleIteratorComponent]
})
export class RowIteratorComponent {
  // "rowData" is a ARRAYS
}

//columnIterator.components.ts
import {Component,forwardRef} from 'angular2/core';
import {RowIteratorComponent} from './rowIterator.component';
import {ModuleIteratorComponent} from './moduleIterator.component';

@Component({
  selector: '[columIterator]',
  template:`
    <div *ngFor="#element of columData">
      <div rowIterator *ngIf="element.row" [ngClass]="element.class" [rowData]="element.row"></div>

      <div moduleIterator *ngIf="element.module" [ngClass]="element.class" [moduleData]="element.module"></div>
    </div>
  `,
  inputs: ['columData'],
  directives: [forwardRef(function(){return RowIteratorComponent;}), ModuleIteratorComponent]
})
export class ColumIteratorComponent{
  // "columData" is a ARRAY
}
```

I have to use the `forwardRef(function() {return RowIteratorComponent;}` function and `forwardRef(function() {return ColumIteratorComponent;})` respectively for the loop in the Beta 0 version and have no problems, but in Versioned beta2 get the following error:

```
EXCEPTION: TypeError: viewFactory_ColumIteratorComponent0 is not a function in [element.column in RowIteratorComponent@2:25]
EXCEPTION: TypeError: viewFactory_ColumIteratorComponent0 is not a function in [element.column in RowIteratorComponent@2:25]BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ angular2.dev.js:22911BrowserDomAdapter.logGroup @ angular2.dev.js:22922ExceptionHandler.call @ angular2.dev.js:1182(anonymous function) @ angular2.dev.js:12562NgZone._notifyOnError @ angular2.dev.js:13485collection_1.StringMapWrapper.merge.onError @ angular2.dev.js:13389Zone.run @ angular2-polyfills.js:1247(anonymous function) @ angular2.dev.js:13408NgZone.run @ angular2.dev.js:13370(anonymous function) @ angular2.dev.js:12661schedulerFn @ angular2.dev.js:12904tryCatcher @ Rx.js:234Subscriber.next @ Rx.js:9703Subject._next @ Rx.js:10202Subject.next @ Rx.js:10166EventEmitter.emit @ angular2.dev.js:12885(anonymous function) @ angular2.dev.js:13301Zone.run @ angular2-polyfills.js:1243NgZone._notifyOnTurnDone @ angular2.dev.js:13300(anonymous function) @ angular2.dev.js:13415zoneBoundFn @ angular2-polyfills.js:1220lib$es6$promise$$internal$$tryCatch @ angular2-polyfills.js:468lib$es6$promise$$internal$$invokeCallback @ angular2-polyfills.js:480lib$es6$promise$$internal$$publish @ angular2-polyfills.js:451(anonymous function) @ angular2-polyfills.js:123Zone.run @ angular2-polyfills.js:1243zoneBoundFn @ angular2-polyfills.js:1220lib$es6$promise$asap$$flush @ angular2-polyfills.js:262
angular2.dev.js:22911 ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: viewFactory_ColumIteratorComponent0 is not a functionBrowserDomAdapter.logError @ angular2.dev.js:22911ExceptionHandler.call @ angular2.dev.js:1191(anonymous function) @ angular2.dev.js:12562NgZone._notifyOnError @ angular2.dev.js:13485collection_1.StringMapWrapper.merge.onError @ angular2.dev.js:13389Zone.run @ angular2-polyfills.js:1247(anonymous function) @ angular2.dev.js:13408NgZone.run @ angular2.dev.js:13370(anonymous function) @ angular2.dev.js:12661schedulerFn @ angular2.dev.js:12904tryCatcher @ Rx.js:234Subscriber.next @ Rx.js:9703Subject._next @ Rx.js:10202Subject.next @ Rx.js:10166EventEmitter.emit @ angular2.dev.js:12885(anonymous function) @ angular2.dev.js:13301Zone.run @ angular2-polyfills.js:1243NgZone._notifyOnTurnDone @ angular2.dev.js:13300(anonymous function) @ angular2.dev.js:13415zoneBoundFn @ angular2-polyfills.js:1220lib$es6$promise$$internal$$tryCatch @ angular2-polyfills.js:468lib$es6$promise$$internal$$invokeCallback @ angular2-polyfills.js:480lib$es6$promise$$internal$$publish @ angular2-polyfills.js:451(anonymous function) @ angular2-polyfills.js:123Zone.run @ angular2-polyfills.js:1243zoneBoundFn @ angular2-polyfills.js:1220lib$es6$promise$asap$$flush @ angular2-polyfills.js:262
angular2.dev.js:22911 ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ angular2.dev.js:22911ExceptionHandler.call @ angular2.dev.js:1194(anonymous function) @ angular2.dev.js:12562NgZone._notifyOnError @ angular2.dev.js:13485collection_1.StringMapWrapper.merge.onError @ angular2.dev.js:13389Zone.run @ angular2-polyfills.js:1247(anonymous function) @ angular2.dev.js:13408NgZone.run @ angular2.dev.js:13370(anonymous function) @ angular2.dev.js:12661schedulerFn @ angular2.dev.js:12904tryCatcher @ Rx.js:234Subscriber.next @ Rx.js:9703Subject._next @ Rx.js:10202Subject.next @ Rx.js:10166EventEmitter.emit @ angular2.dev.js:12885(anonymous function) @ angular2.dev.js:13301Zone.run @ angular2-polyfills.js:1243NgZone._notifyOnTurnDone @ angular2.dev.js:13300(anonymous function) @ angular2.dev.js:13415zoneBoundFn @ angular2-polyfills.js:1220lib$es6$promise$$internal$$tryCatch @ angular2-polyfills.js:468lib$es6$promise$$internal$$invokeCallback @ angular2-polyfills.js:480lib$es6$promise$$internal$$publish @ angular2-polyfills.js:451(anonymous function) @ angular2-polyfills.js:123Zone.run @ angular2-polyfills.js:1243zoneBoundFn @ angular2-polyfills.js:1220lib$es6$promise$asap$$flush @ angular2-polyfills.js:262
angular2.dev.js:22911 TypeError: viewFactory_ColumIteratorComponent0 is not a function...
```