# Angular 2.0.0-beta.1 breaking change: Components with nesting break as siblings

Tags: angular

I noticed an issue when upgrading from 2.0.0.0-beta.0 to 2.0.0.0-beta.1

My sample code below is working fine in beta.0 ([see plunkr 1](http://plnkr.co/edit/nyVEYv2HMPRYVDRzFFR7)) but not in beta.1 ([see punkr 2](http://plnkr.co/edit/TicTf7LmzxFjyrglqNaT)). It consists of 1 simple dummy component, and 2 grouping components each containing that dummy component. I want to display those 2 grouping components side-by-side, as siblings:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'dummy-item',
    template: 'Hi I am a dummy item!'
})
export class DummyItem {}


@Component({
    selector: 'group-a',
    directives: [DummyItem],
    template:`
        <div>
            group A:
            <dummy-item></dummy-item>
            <dummy-item></dummy-item>
        </div>
    `
})
export class GroupA {}


@Component({
    selector: 'group-b',
    directives: [DummyItem],
    template:`
        <div>
            group B:
            <dummy-item></dummy-item>
            <dummy-item></dummy-item>
        </div>
    `
})
export class GroupB {}


@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template:`
        <group-a></group-a>
        <group-b></group-b>
    `,
    directives: [DummyItem, GroupA, GroupB]
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

I though that this was the normal way of nesting components, so I did not expect this to break with a minor update.

I am very curious to know why the below error occurs, and how it can be prevented. I have read the [changelog](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md), but cannot derive a solution from it.

Here is the stacktrace:

```
EXCEPTION: TypeError: viewFactory_DummyItem0 is not a functionBrowserDomAdapter.logError @ angular2.dev.js:22690
angular2.dev.js:22690 STACKTRACE:BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ angular2.dev.js:22690
angular2.dev.js:22690 TypeError: viewFactory_DummyItem0 is not a function
    at viewFactory_GroupB0 (viewFactory_GroupB:88:1)
    at viewFactory_AppComponent0 (viewFactory_AppComponent:88:1)
    at HostViewFactory.viewFactory_HostAppComponent0 [as viewFactory] (viewFactory_HostAppComponent:75:1)
    at AppViewManager_.createRootHostView (https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.1/angular2.dev.js:9172:34)
    at https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.1/angular2.dev.js:12189:46
    at Zone.run (https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.1/angular2-polyfills.js:138:17)
    at Zone.run (https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.1/angular2.dev.js:13247:32)
    at zoneBoundFn (https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.1/angular2-polyfills.js:111:19)
    at lib$es6$promise$$internal$$tryCatch (https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.1/angular2-polyfills.js:1511:16)
    at lib$es6$promise$$internal$$invokeCallback (https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.1/angular2-polyfills.js:1523:17)

-----async gap-----
Error
    at _getStacktraceWithUncaughtError (https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.1/angular2-polyfills.js:2195:26)
    at Zone.fork (https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.1/angular2-polyfills.js:2253:40)
    at Zone.bind (https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.1/angular2-polyfills.js:109:48)
    at bindArguments (https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.1/angular2-polyfills.js:980:29)
    at lib$es6$promise$promise$$Promise.obj.(anonymous function) [as then] (https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.1/angular2-polyfills.js:1000:37)
    at DynamicComponentLoader_.loadAsRoot (https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.1/angular2.dev.js:12188:49)
    at di_1.provide.useFactory (https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.1/angular2.dev.js:12286:39)
    at Injector._instantiate (https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.1/angular2.dev.js:11297:19)
    at Injector._instantiateProvider (https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.1/angular2.dev.js:11230:21)
    at Injector._new (https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.1/angular2.dev.js:11220:19)

-----async gap-----
Error
    at _getStacktraceWithUncaughtError (https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.1/angular2-polyfills.js:2195:26)
    at Zone.fork (https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.1/angular2-polyfills.js:2253:40)
    at NgZone._createInnerZone (https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.1/angular2.dev.js:13235:39)
    at new NgZone (https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.1/angular2.dev.js:13101:32)
    at createNgZone (https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.1/angular2.dev.js:12308:12)
    at PlatformRef_.application (https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.1/angular2.dev.js:12383:31)
    at Object.bootstrap (https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.1/angular2.dev.js:24410:64)
    at execute (http://run.plnkr.co/gclpu8pCsklPMCpi/app/boot.ts!transpiled:12:23)
    at u (https://code.angularjs.org/tools/system.js:5:97)
    at Object.execute (https://code.angularjs.org/tools/system.js:5:3188)
```

Comment: Same thing happens to this: https://github.com/auth0/angular2-authentication-sample/issues/48

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/34833913/4933038

Comment: @EricMartinez - thanks a lot! if you post your comment as an answer, I will upvote and accept it:)